# in Angular How to call controller in other file.html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Im using Angular I want to call mainController in other page html but I found an error like this : Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] ??

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>test</title>
       
 <script src="public/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/lodash/lodash.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/app.js"></script>
 <script src="services/apiService.js"></script>
 <script src="controllers/mainCrtl.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body data-ng-controller="mainCrtl" data-ng-app="training">

{{ formers }}
    ok just for testing !

    </body>
    </html>
```

```js
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.2/$injector/modulerr?p0=training&p1=Error%3…F127.0.0.1%3A9090%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A332)
    at angular.js:38
    at angular.js:4779
    at q (angular.js:357)
    at g (angular.js:4740)
    at db (angular.js:4662)
    at c (angular.js:1842)
    at Mc (angular.js:1863)
    at qe (angular.js:1748)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (angular.js:33129)
    at j (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2)
```

Comment: Please, post the full stacktrace message.

Comment: I added it ....

Comment: You're linking to a minified version of AngularJS wit this `<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`. This ways it is hard to get more details about the error, try to link to the non-minified version of AngularJS: `<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` and see what the stacktrace shows now. This should be a more readable stacktrace

Comment: can you post your app.js please?

Comment: I think I have to use ngRoute !!  so this is my app.js         var trainingApp = angular.module('training', ['daypilot']);

Comment: Based on what I see. you are injecting 'daypilot', but I don't see any 'daypilot' related script ref in your html.

Comment: i used 'daypilot' in index.html but i want to use the same controller in other page.html to use some object scope ..

Comment: 1) In your app.js, you injected 'daypilot' as a module. Angular won't recognize this 'daypilot' unless you have reference point to 'daypilot'. This maybe why Angular complains. 2) Data is not supposed to shared among controllers. If you need some data/function that need to be access across different controllers. Create a service to contain them.